# How does Matlab set serial timeout function work?

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I have a sensor connected to my computer and I downloaded some code that connects it with MATLAB over a serial port.

I have this code which initializes the connection and sets some parameters:

```
sport = serial(com_port); % assigns the object sport to serial port

set(sport, 'BaudRate', 9600);
... other configs
set(sport, 'Timeout', Timeout);
set(sport, 'ReadAsyncMode', 'continuous');
```

Where Timeout is a variable set to `5`.

What does the `set(sport, 'Timeout', Timeout);` line actually do? I have looked through MATLAB's Serial Port Devices documentation [-Found Here-](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/serial-port-devices.html) but I cannot find the documentation on setting a serial port's timeout.

My original idea was that this value was the time my `sport` object was given to gather data, but the next line, `set(sport, 'ReadAsyncMode', 'continuous');` tells the device to continually stream data.

Also, I don't want to go changing too many values without knowing exactly what I'm doing, for fear of breaking anything. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the description of the `TimeOut` property [in the matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_external/timeout.html).
The property `TimeOut` sets the "Waiting time to complete a read or write operation"

In the `Contents` menu on the left you can select other properties, such as `ReadAsyncMode` and read about them.